# I am getting a type error when I am trying to replace

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to do a conditional replacing of values in one column(**age_cat**) by values in another column(**stillbirth**) but it's giving me a type error

## TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

basically, I need it to say age_cat is "SB" if report_stillbirth is Yes

| 'report_stillbirth' | 'age_cat' |
| --- | --- |
| No | 1 |
| Yes | 0 |
| No | 2 |
| No | 4 |

**report_stillbirth** is a string
**age_cat** is an integer

```
df.loc[df['report_stillbirth'] == "Yes", 'age_cat'] = "SB"
```

I have tried to change the type of the age_cat to string with:

```
df['age_cat'] = df['age_cat'].astype(str)
```

Comment: Maybe I don't quite understand the output you want to get. Can you add the desired output example?

Comment: thanks, i'll remember that next time as @Ingwersen_erik has already game an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df['age_cat'] = np.where(df['report_stillbirth'] == 'Yes', 'SB', df['age_cat'])
```

**Example:**

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


choices = ['Yes', 'No']

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'report_stillbirth': np.random.choice(choices, 10),
        'age_cat': np.random.randint(1, 15, 10)
    }
)

print(df)
# prints:
#
#   report_stillbirth  age_cat
# 0                No        6
# 1                No        1
# 2               Yes        4
# 3               Yes       12
# 4               Yes       13
# 5                No        2
# 6                No        7
# 7               Yes        1
# 8               Yes        7
# 9               Yes       10
```

Now, if we apply [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where):

```py
df['age_cat'] = np.where(df['report_stillbirth'] == 'Yes', 'SB', df['age_cat'])

print(df)
#
# Prints:
#
#   report_stillbirth age_cat
# 0                No       6
# 1                No       1
# 2               Yes      SB
# 3               Yes      SB
# 4               Yes      SB
# 5                No       2
# 6                No       7
# 7               Yes      SB
# 8               Yes      SB
# 9               Yes      SB
```

Screenshot of the executed cell:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much @Ingwersen_erik worked perfectly, I'll have to take a closer look at numpy